# How to set up a nested field in postman

Tags: json, rest, postman

I have some issues using Postman to test my RESTful api. It has nested field "screenshots" and I don't know how to propery set it up in Postman form-data. Should I use pre request scripts or Postman has built-in fuctions to do this directly in form-data field? Thank you.

Request data structure:

```
data = {
    'title': 'Film123',
    'poster_image': 'base64string',
    'content_rating': 'NC-17',
    'genres': [1, 2, 3], 
    'actors': [1, 2, 3], 
    'country': 'USA', 
    'release_date': '2022-03-14', 
    'director': 'test director', 
    'description': 'Test description', 
    'studio': 'Test studio',
    'screenshots': [
        {
            "image": 'base64string',
        },
        {
            "image": 'base64string',
        },  
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to change the request body to raw > json and use environment variables where necessary.